# Incorrect Event Users count on Answers

Tags: google-fabric

I currently have a Point of Sale application that allows for a user to login, make a purchase, and logout on an iPad. Each device supports multiple users, but I am noticing incorrect counts for "Event users". I am tracking logins, signups, and setting the Crashlytics userIdentifier property. What else do I need to do make sure Answers is properly tracking this information?

For example, I have had 30 users login to my application and go through the purchase flow, but Answers states that there have only been "2 Event Users".

Answer (score 0):

Mike from Fabric here. An event user in this case would be connected to the device that is sending the event, not the user logged into the app which is likely the source of the disconnect.

Comment: Hey Mike, Thanks for the response. Are there plans for adding a logout event that would help address this issue?

Comment: Anytime. No plans currently to add this in, but if that changes will update my answer.